# Unordered xsd:all elements followed by another element

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

How can I write an XSD for the following XML?

```
<A></A>
<B></B>
<C></C>
<D></D>
<E></E>
<E></E>
```

*A,B,C,D* just have *zero or one*. And they don't have sequence. It could be *D,C,B,A*. And in the very end, there are *one or more E* element(s).

I have tried multiple ways, but can't get it done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're blocked by a non-orthogonality of XML Schema.  You'd think that the following should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="top">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:all>
          <xs:element name="A" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="B" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="C" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:all>
        <xs:element name="E" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

However, it does not.  XSD's `xs:all` construct is a second-class citizen; it cannot appear in a `xs:sequence`.

**Recommendation**:  Drop the "any order" allowance from your requirements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="top">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="A" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="B" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="C" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="D" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="E" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Allowing any order of elements ends up being less important in practice than in theory, especially given non-orthogonality such as the above and the potential for clashes with [Unique Particle Attribution](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cos-nonambig).

Comment: ........................ It don't like it in sequences.... Because my xml will be user defined, I don't want the sequence bring the unconvinence of users.

Comment: Sorry, but something has to give because your requirements conflict.  I suggest that sacrificing ordering is a sensible way forward.  You could instead use a validation method other than XSD if you'd prefer.  You could change your markup constraints in another acceptable way, perhaps.  Are you open to adding a wrapper element around A, B, C, and D?

Comment: Sorry... I don't want to add a wrapper element around A,B,C and D. If I want to add the wrapper element, why don't I add the wrapper element around the multiple Es?

Comment: Because you said that the E's must appear *after* the unordered A, B, C, and D.  Wrapping the E's doesn't help with the problem that `xs:all` cannot appear in a sequence.

Comment: You are right. So there is no way for XML schema to solve that. Right?

Comment: Well, if Es canot be anywhere, is there any solution except for changing the structure?

Comment: *So there is no way for XML schema to solve that. Right?*   XML Schema teases that it can do it by offering `xs:all` and `xs:sequence` but then unfortunately falls short because of limitations it places on `xs:all`.